# PHP: Что выбрать для локальной песочницы кусков кода?

Tags: php, windows

История следующая: иногда бывает нужно запустить некую песочницу, вставить туда код на `php` (более ничего не интересует), минимально подредактировать его, после чего нажать одну единственную кнопку и увидеть результат выполнения этого кода.

Код обычно бывает в виде проверки какого-нибудь массива, в виде простой функции и тому подобного - то есть вывода хватает строго консольного, однако одновременно с этим хочется некий отдельный от основной `IDE (PhpStorm)` инструмент, при этом умеющий минимально в редактирование кода, его подсветку и тому подобные функции.

Ранее я использовал для этих целей `Brackets.io`, в нем был удобный для этих целей плагин. Но плагин протух, а тот, что я нашел взамен старого, не слишком здорово работает - например, он выводит данные реально в консоль, запуская отдельный экз. `cmd.exe`, тогда как старый умел забирать вывод из консоли в окошко в самом `Brackets`.

В связи с этим было решено попробовать найти новый, удобный и современный вариант для описанной песочницы. Понятно, что они есть и онлайн, но это не слишком оправдано, когда речь идет о простых кусках `php`-кода, на мой взгляд. Будет здорово, если кто-то поделится опытом организации подобного в `Sublime` или `Atom` - никогда с ними не работал, и возможно это будет не лишний опыт.

Comment: Всегда можно воспользоваться online инструментами, например https://repl.it/repls/AromaticMonthlyBrowser . Попробуйте ввести в левой части строку 'phpinfo()' и нажать вверху кноку 'Run'

Comment: Я далек от PHP, но в IDE обычно бывают встроенные инструменты подобного рода. Например, при поиске по PhpStorm выходит слово Scratches: [1](https://twitter.com/phpstorm/status/869176836047110148), [2](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/scratches.html). Это не подойдет?

Comment: @defaultlocale не-не, там-то я знаю как все сделать, но хочется именно отдельного приложения-песочницы, зачастую это удобнее, чем в даже уже открытой IDE все делать.

Comment: @Kosmos - да про онлайн я в курсе, но про них же в тексте моего вопроса есть уточнение, что это не то, что я ищу.

Comment: Сделайте собственную страничку, на которой будет только `textarea` c хайлайт js библиотечкой. По кнопке отправляет текст на бэкенд, где делается только `try(eval($programtext) catch (Exception $e ) {..}` и возвращать результат

Comment: @DmitryKozlov я могу это сделать. Но зачем? :-) Условия задачи совершенно иные - попользоваться каким-нибудь для себя свежим редактором, при том обладающим нужным функционалом песочницы, при том не являющимся онлайн - таких сервисов и без меня уже вагон.